# Bootstrap 3 column grid not working correctly in IE

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular7

I am developing a responsive website with angular 7 and Bootstrap 3. Works perfectly on all browser but IE. In IE11, wherever I am using col-lg-12, content goes to the next line.

Comment: You're not zoomed in are you?

Comment: @gilliduck No, I am not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to your head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Comment: I have added following code for IE 11 but still it's not working.         <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=11">